# several thousand/thousands day - which form

Tags: grammatical-number

What is correct please - thousand wuth s or without s? ... of the order of several thousand**s** days.

Comment: _several thousands of days_ or _several thousand days_ are both correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

> several thousands of days

or you could alternatively say:

> several thousand days

Which are both correct.